# In Python 2.7, not able to change flag using chflags () for file as it should not be renamed or deleted

Tags: python

Set a flag so that file may not be renamed or deleted.

```
import os

print os.chflags( "D:\\TAX\\testdemo\\backup.txt", os.SF_NOUNLINK)

os.rename("backup.txt","upback.txt")
```

**Error :**

```
print os.chflags( "D:\\TAX\\testdemo\\backup.txt", os.SF_NOUNLINK)           
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'chflags'
```

Comment: `chflags()` is only available on systems that that support this particular system call, which does include most BSDs but does *not* include Windows. I'm pretty sure, NTFS does not support the flag, anyway.

Comment: So I wont be able to execute this method on Windows machine?

Comment: No, Windows does not have this system call. What stops you from using file permissions to achieve the same result?

Comment: Sorry.. but not able to understand.